# Hibernate data in handler

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have a problem with Hibernate and many-to-one relationship.
Indeed, after getting my object corresponding to the table , the purpose of the foreign key remains `null`. But there is a `handler` which has a field that contains the target `data`

[Debug image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oG6xK.png)

Thank for your help

Zorn

Comment: What you have there is perfectly normal. Javassist proxies are created for lazy loading. What matters is that you can do `user.getRole().getName()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!I added `lazy='false` in my xml file and it works like a charm !

Comment: You shouldn't add lazy=false. I repeat: what you're seeing in the debugger is perfectly normal. Calling user.getRole().getName() WILL work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing is normal because you have a lazy='true' set in your XML, you are able to call your method normally but if you want to get rid of that (I don't recommend) then you need to add

> lazy='false'

in your XML file.